# Pagination with arrows in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my javascript code:

```
function setPage(currentPage){
    currentPage = parseInt(currentPage) + 1;
    var last = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Attempt"));
    var lastPage = last.length - 1;
    var prevcurPage = currentPage - 1;
    var prevcurPage2 = currentPage - 2;
    var nextcurPage = currentPage + 1;
    var nextcurPage2 = currentPage + 2;
    var content = "";
    if(lastPage == 1){

    }else{
    if(currentPage == 1){
        if(lastPage > 2){
            content+=" [<a href=''>"+currentPage+"</a>] | ";
            content+=" <a href=''>"+nextcurPage+"</a> | ";
            content+=" <a href=''>"+nextcurPage2+"</a> | ";
        }else{
            content+=" [<a href=''>"+currentPage+"</a>] | ";
            content+=" <a href=''>"+nextcurPage+"</a> | ";
        }

    }else if(currentPage == lastPage){
        if(lastPage > 2){
            content+=" <a href=''>"+prevcurPage2+"</a> | ";
            content+=" <a href=''>"+prevcurPage+"</a> | ";
            content+=" [<a href=''>"+currentPage+"</a>] | ";
        }else{
            content+=" <a href=''>"+prevcurPage+"</a> | ";
            content+=" [<a href=''>"+currentPage+"</a>] | ";
        }
    }else{
            content+=" <a href=''>"+prevcurPage+"</a> | ";
            content+=" [<a href=''>"+currentPage+"</a>] | ";
            content+=" <a href=''>"+nextcurPage+"</a> | ";
    }
}
```

The currentPage is started in `0`; so I need to add `1`;
Why is it not displaying the correct pagination? And how do I put it an arrows?

I want this to show,

```
currentpage = 0; [1] | 2 | 3 >
currentpage = 2; 1 | 2 | [3] | 4 | 5 >
currentpage = 7; < 4 | 5 | [6]
```

Comment: Have you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (currentPage > 3)
    content += " < ";
content += currentPage - 2 > 0 ? "<a href=''>"+(currentPage - 2)+"</a> | " : '';
content += currentPage - 1 > 0 ? "<a href=''>"+(currentPage - 1)+"</a> | " : '';

content += "[" + currentPage + "]";

content += currentPage + 1 <= lastPage ? " | <a href=''>"+(currentPage + 1)+"</a>" : '';
content += currentPage + 2 <= lastPage ? " | <a href=''>"+(currentPage + 2)+"</a>" : '';
if (currentPage < lastPage - 2)
    content += " > ";
```

Or for better flexibility, use some sort of a range variable:

```
var range = 2;

if (currentPage > range + 1)
    content += " < ";

for (var a = range; a > 0; a--)
    content += currentPage - a > 0 ? "<a href=''>"+(currentPage - a)+"</a> | " : '';

content += "[" + currentPage + "]";

for (var a = 1; a <= range; a++)
    content += currentPage + a <= lastPage ? " | <a href=''>"+(currentPage + a)+"</a>" : '';

if (currentPage < lastPage - range)
    content += " > ";
```

Comment: what do you mean of " : ' '; "?

Comment: That would be a ternary operator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A. Basically if the condition is true, take the left side, otherwise take the right side. So if it's false, it adds/concatenates nothing.

Comment: how to add an anchor in it? "<a href="

Comment: i removed the loop because when in loop, the results are, [1] | 2 | 3 [1] | 2 | 3 [1] | 2 | 3

Comment: i changed the "<a href=''> to "<a href='attempt.html?q='"+(currentPage - 2)+">" .. and it is not working. can u update it again

Comment: Sorry. I have no idea why I put that in a loop. It's late.

Comment: You're missing a closing arrow in that snippet by the way. It should all work now if you've implemented it correctly.